# Obtain argument of tensor product

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I want to obtain the argument of a TensorProduct as a list of elements by applying another function.

For example, I wish to write a function h which, when applied to a tensor product, produces the arguments as follows

```
h[TensorProduct[a__]]:={a}
```

However, this doesn't work. The output is simply

```
TensorProduct[a]
```

Strangely it works for heads different from TensorProduct. For example

```
h[g[a__]]:={a}
```

works.

I can get the right output by doing for example

```
h[TensorProduct[a__]]:=List@@TensorProduct[a]
```

but why can I not just extract the argument in the previous way?

Answer (score 1):

Give `h` the attribute `HoldFirst` to prevent `TensorProduct` from evaluating:

```
ClearAll[h]
SetAttributes[h, HoldFirst]
h[TensorProduct[a__]] := {a}
h[TensorProduct[a, b]]
```

> {a, b}